# UDP recv fails when receiving more than 8 bytes

Tags: c++, udp, recv

I want to receive data via c++ non-blocking recv and everything works as expected for up to 8 bytes payload but when I try to receive 9 bytes or more, recv returns -1 while errno is 0.

Here are the relevant parts of my code. Return values of init-fcns are checked and ok, just left that out to shorten the snippet.

Init Code:

```
WSADATA w;
HANDLE soc, sem;
SOCKADDR_IN addr;

err = WSAStartup(0x0202, &w);
soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
memset((void *)&addr, '\0', sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(50001);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ADDR_ANY;

sem = CreateEvent(nullptr, false, false, nullptr);
WSAEventSelect(soc, sem, FD_READ);
```

Receiver thread:

```
char buf[10000];
int bytes_read = 0;

while (true){
    WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, enqueue_sem, false, WSA_INFINITE, false);

    bytes_read = recv(soc, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    cout << bytes_read << ":" << strerror(errno) << endl;
    cout << buf << endl;
}
```

When I'm sending 9 bytes or more, the packet is ok (checked via whireshark) and even the first 8 bytes are written to buf, but all following bytes are lost.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Eight bytes sounds suspiciously like a 64-bit variable to me. Probably you are using a variable for a buffer instead of an address or vice versa.

Comment: Expanding on @Dwayne's comment: I bet in your real code `buf` is not a `char` array, but a `char*` pointer. `sizeof(buf)` is then the size of the pointer, not the size of the buffer it points to.

Comment: Sounds really suspicious, but even if my buf would be just 8 bytes long, recv should copy all data up to sizeof(buf) and discard the remaining part without error. Right? Any further ideas? Btw.: buf is defined as char buf[10000];

Comment: `recv` reports as an error the fact that the datagram was only partially received. Specifically, `WSAEMSGSIZE`: "The message was too large to fit into the specified buffer and was truncated."

Comment: Is there a way to get the reason why recv returns -1?

Comment: From `recv`'s documentation: Otherwise, a value of `SOCKET_ERROR` is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling `WSAGetLastError`.

Comment: call WSAGetLastError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wild guess is that your code looks slightly different to what you show us:

```
 char global_buf[10000];
 char *buf = global_buf;
 recv(soc,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
```

In this case `sizeof(buf)` would not be 10000 but instead 8 (size of pointer on 64bit platforms), which would explain why you only can receive 8 bytes.

Comment: Thank you and @Dwayne for your hint, that was indeed the problem, but I'm still not really satisfied. Are there any possibilities to get a more precise error code from recv than just -1?

Comment: See the [documentation for recv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx). It says that you get the more detailed error by calling `WSAGetLastError`. In your case this would probably result in `WSAEMSGSIZE`: "The message was too large to fit into the specified buffer and was truncated".